# How can I use an onclick HTML attribute to call a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why but my JavaScript isn't working in my HTML. I want to make a little "clickAdd" but it won't work. I tried everything but I didn't get it to work.

```js
var points = 0;

function clickAdd() {
    points += 1;
    document.getElementById("clickDisplay").innerHTML = points;
    window.alert("Hallo");
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Clicker 0.1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1 id="clickDisplay"></h1>
     <button  type="button" onclick="clickAdd">Click me!</button>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mainscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick="clickAdd()"` <---

Comment: thanks works i forgot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function in the `onClick` attribute by adding `()` at the end

```js
var points = 0;

function clickAdd() {
    points += 1;
    document.getElementById("clickDisplay").innerHTML = points;
    window.alert("Hallo");
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Clicker 0.1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1 id="clickDisplay"></h1>
     <button  type="button" onclick="clickAdd()">Click me!</button> <!-- <==== Added () here -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mainscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Omg i forgot this i made so long no javascript and html sorry :D thanks xD

Comment: @SchdowNVIDIA Happy to help! we all oversee things like this every now and then. ^^ 
If your question has been resolved, please don't forget to mark the answer that worked for you by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. This helps other people with similar questions find their answer in a fast manner.